# problems in encode after parsing an XML

Tags: android

After i get the response of an XML, and read the doc then list it into listview,
it seems that there's a problem in unicode or something .... I don't realy understand where's the problem . I use Arabic words in the XML file using encoding="utf-8".
but after it parsed,it shows like "Ø±ÙˆØ§ÙŠØ§".

Can someone explain me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!! i just added "UTF-8" to the HTTP response using EntityUtils

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
```